# Disjoint varieties under affine transformation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $X, Y \subset K^{n^2}$ be algebraic sets such that $X$ is an irreducible hypersurface and $Y$ is irreducible of dimension $n$. (Assume $n>1$).

Does there exists some $v \in K^{n^2}$ such that $Y+v=\{ y+v \colon y\in Y\}$ is disjoint from $X$? Is the set of such $v \in K^n$ Zariski open?

Over $\mathbb{C}$ this can be done using topological/analytic tools such as Sard's theorem, but I am not sure if this is true over any $K$ or if we need any condition on $X$, on $Y$, or on $n$?

Comment: I guess by $v \in K^n$ you mean $v \in K^{n^2}$, and that you want to assume $n > 1$

Comment: @math54321 right. I fixed that now. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Let $Z$ be the Zariski closure of the set $\{(x, y) : x \in X, y \in Y, x = y\} \subset K^{n^2} \times K^{n^2}$. By the Chevalley-Bertini theorem, for almost all $v \in K^{n^2}$, the intersection $Z \cap \{(x, y) : x = y + v\}$ has codimension at least 1 in $Z$, hence is not equal to $Z$. This is equivalent to the corollary.

2. It will typically not be Zariski open, since it will fail to contain certain special directions along which $Y$ intersects $X$. But in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are in general position, it should indeed be Zariski open, I think.